# FOS UserBundle customize login -> add a field

Tags: symfony, authentication, customization, fosuserbundle

Actually, I use FOS to login users.

```
security.yml
            form_login:
               provider: fos_userbundle
               csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
               default_target_path: /
```

Now, I would like to extend the login form so that it is neccessary to enter also a customer ID instead of username/password only.

I read the overwritng fos form https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_forms.md but it is not clear enough for me how to handle this for the reason that I also have to check the field client_id at login now.

Has anyone a tut where I can have a look at? Or a hint howto set it up?

Comment: You want to use your custom field instead of username/email field?

Comment: If by check you mean, check if the value provided by the user for client_id is acceptable ,then search for 'fosuser validators'.if you want to identify your user by it, you can either override the mapping of the FOS/../User class to get $username from client_id field in the database( can be done via doctrine overrideAttribute).but then you won't be able to load your users by their username.if you want to bypass that limitation you probably have to make your custom user provider.

Comment: The problem is, that I need the Client Id to identifiy only which client. There may be two users with the username "foo". One at client "12345" and anotherone at "65765". Therefor, I would like to setup the client id as a text field where it is neccessary to insert your id  for oligni. So that I will have to check : which cleint, whcih username and password.